# Converting 8 Bit Images to 16 bit with Php ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

What I'm trying to do is convert an 8 bit image to a 16 bit image using php ImageMagick. With Imagick it's as easy as `convert /location/image.jpg -colors 8 -depth 16  txt:-`. In the PHP docs it shows that you can do it using `$imagick->setImageDepth(16);` but the problem is that it doesn't give you the 16 bit hex / rgb numbers.

Is there an advantage to using 16 bit when trying to extract colors from an image? If not then I'm wondering isn't the php function working?

Here is what I get from `$mapColor->getColor()`:

```
Array
(
    [r] => 51
    [g] => 51
    [b] => 51
    [a] => 1
)
Array
```

Here is my code for getting colors:

```
// Create new instance
$imagick = new Imagick($image);

// Set number of colors
$numberColors = 6;

// Set colorspace
$colorSpace = Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB;

// Set tree depth
$treeDepth = 0;

// Set dither
$dither = false;

// Convert to 16 bit
$imagick->setImageDepth(16);

// Quantize image to number of colors
$imagick->quantizeImage($numberColors, $colorSpace, $treeDepth, $dither, false);

// Get Image Dimensions
$sizes = $imagick->getImageGeometry();

// Get image's histogram
$pixels = $imagick->getImageHistogram();

// Temp cache dimensions
$totalSize = $sizes['width'] * $sizes['height'];


// Loop through each pixel
foreach($pixels as $k => $v) {

    // Get total number of color instances
    $count = $v->getColorCount();

    // Get colormap at pixel
    $mapColor = $imagick->getImageColormapColor($k);

    // Get colore
    $rgbColor = $mapColor->getColor();

    // Convert to RGB hex values
    $red = str_pad(dechex($rgbColor['r']), 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $green = str_pad(dechex($rgbColor['g']), 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $blue = str_pad(dechex($rgbColor['b']), 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

    // Set hexadecimal
    $hex = $red.$green.$blue;

    // Calculate color percentage
    $percentage = (100 * $count) / $totalSize;

    // Push colors into array
    $colors[] = array(
        'red'           => $rgbColor['r'],
        'green'         => $rgbColor['g'],
        'blue'          => $rgbColor['b'],
        'hex'           => $hex,
        'count'         => $count,
        'percentage'    => $percentage,
    );
}

print_r($colors);
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Your image you "double size" without any improvement.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive you are getting 8 bit numbers? For example, if I had the 2 bit number 3A and I converted it to 4 bits, it would be 003A. If I asked for it, I would get 003A, but anything I do with it will just show 3A because the two leading zero bytes would be dropped.

Comment: Felippe, that's what I thought, but I've seen another fast search engine using 16 bit and wondering about advantage.

Comment: @kainaw I just updated my question with the RGB output from `mapColor->getColor()` and added my code for colors

Comment: As I pointed out, 51 in 8-bit is 51. 51 in 16-bit is 51. 51 in 32-bit is 51. 51 in 2048-bit is 51. How does this tell you what the bit depth of the image is?

Comment: @kainaw not saying you're wrong at all, but I get this when running `convert /location/image.jpg -colors 8 -depth 16  txt:-` =====> `# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 7,1,65535,srgb" [1]=> string(73) "0,0: (13110,13110,13109) #333633363335 srgb(20.0046%,20.0046%,20.0031%)"` and when I run that same command but with 8 bit =====> `"# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 7,1,255,srgb" [1]=> string(41) "0,0: (13107,13107,13107) #333333 grey20"`

Comment: What is the point of trying to get 16-bit colours when you only know them to 8-bit accuracy? It's kind of like insisting your fridge can tell you how much beer it contains down to the nearest millilitre when all you have in it are 1 gallon casks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can't say I have a reason at this point... I'm more so just wondering advantages + disadvantages.

Comment: The disadvantage is it takes twice the space. I can't see any advantage.

Comment: "What is the point of trying to get 16-bit colours when you only know them to 8-bit accuracy?" Some programs accept only limited formats on input, however "What I'm trying to do is convert an 8 bit image to a 16 bit image using php ImageMagick" Well, not you're not - you appear to be getting an image histogram and then using that......what is your actual goal?